How to use criterion for benchmarking in rust without having a lib in cargo toml?
I will go straight to the point. This is my folder structure
|----Project HEAD
  |-------------------src
         |-------------------copy.rs
         |-------------------main.rs
         |-------------------helper.rs
         |-------------------copy_bench.rs


and this is my cargo toml:
[package]
name = "copy_experiments"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.37"
crossbeam = "0.8.4"
rayon = "1.10.0"
tabled = "0.15.0"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = {version = "0.5.1"}

[[bench]]
name = "copy_bench"
path = "src/copy_bench.rs"
harness = false

Now I have multiple functions written in copy.rs that I want to bench mark
how can I do this without having to reorganize everything?
I tried converting copy.rs to lib but then copy.rs cannot use functions from helper.rs anymore
I would prefer to not reorganize anything if possible
for example:
copy.rs:
use crate::helper::somefunc;  // this becomes unresolved if copy.rs is converted to lib


without converting copy.rs to lib I cannot seem use function from copy even though they are in the same folder
as soon as I mention the path under [[bench]] use crate::copy; becomes unresolved
What is the solution to this? I am usually used to C, where I can include whatever I want however I want but this is puzzling and any guidance towards the right direction is appreciated.

I would just copy the functions you want to bench to your benchmark, or export them temporarily.

@ChayimFriedman, I mean that is a solution but is there no other elegant way to fix this issue that is reasonable and does not include copy pasting everything? for example lets say i introduce find.rs and rename copy_bench.rs to bench.rs where I bench both finding and copying then i have to again copy everything from find.rs. it does solve the problem   but does not feel right

Export it temporarily then hide it again?

@ChayimFriedman that might be what I am looking for but I do not know how to export them temporarily and then hide it again or what exactly that means

Make it pub, run your benchmark, remove the pub.

I tried that pub mod copy;  and pub use copy::cp;
and mod bench_lib.rs  in main.rs and use super::*; in bench_lib.rs but then I get the error
  |
1 | use super::*;
  |     ^^^^^ there are too many leading `super` keywords```

This feels like an XY Problem.  The fact that you are having an issue with your benchmark is an indication that your project is poorly structured, but rather than solving that, you seem to be trying to find ways to avoid it.  Your project isn't big enough yet that it should be a major problem to restructure it now, but when the project is much larger and other things don't work well, it might be a much more difficult process.

It should be use your_crate_name::copy::cp (benchmarks see the crate from the outside). Also, conventionally you put benchmarks under /benches.

@ChayimFriedman thank you for your guidance. I finally realized, The way I was creating the lib was wrong and then I tried to solve the problem without creating lib but that was not the solution.

To successfully bench multiple modules in Rust with criterion. You will need a lib folder. You can create your lib as such by putting the following line in your cargo.toml:
[lib]
name = "lib"
path = "src/lib/mod.rs"

In the lib folder mod.rs will be the entry point for all your submodules. if you have a lib folder structure like:
|--------lib
     |---------copy.rs
     |---------etc.rs
     |---------etc2.rs
     |---------mod.rs


then your mod.rs should look like :
pub mod copy;
pub mod etc1;
pub mod etc2;

after that if you have a helper module lets say in this case etc1 and you want to use the helper module in the copy module then you should put the following in copy.rs
use crate::ect1::somefunc2;

then you in your bench.rs file you are able to use
use lib::copy::somefunc;

Hope it helps newbies like me.
